# How do i make the application get the time by itself automatically?

Tags: c#, arrays

I've googled about but still haven't found what I'm looking for. What I want to happen is  i want the application get the Date&time by itself automatically so you wont have to type it in manually.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace RegisterApp
 {
     class TimeRegister
     {
         static void Register(string[] args)
         {
        Console.WriteLine("Time of Arrival Program!");
        Console.ReadLine();

        string[] EmployeeName = new string[5];
        string TimeofArr;
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome, Kindly enter your Name: ");
            EmployeeName[i] = Console.ReadLine();

            string TimeofArr = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(TimeofArr);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

}
```

}

Are there any SIMPLE work around, I say simple because I am new to c# and not aware of all the concepts/terminology. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question - you may want to reword it. Although given my understanding it looks like you are already getting the current date/time automatically in the `TimeofArr = DateTime.Now.ToString();` line.

Comment: You already have a `TimeofArr = DateTime.Now.ToString();` which does this.What other problems related to that time do you have ?

Comment: @chrisP when i compile it requests for the time of arr instead of automatically getting the system time

Comment: @nos its still requesting for user defined time instead of automatically getting i want to app to get the time of arr by itself auto

Comment: @AdetunjiOdusami No it doesn't. It prints out the time. Then you have a `Console.ReadLine();`, which just waits until you press Enter. You could remove the last `Console.ReadLine();`. But we still don't know what you want to actually do with the DateTime.Now.ToString(), right now you're just printing it out to the screen.

Comment: @nos i just want the time of Arrival on the screen (automatically) along side the inputed name

Comment: @AdetunjiOdusami You mean `Console.WriteLine("Name: " + EmployeeName[i] + " ArrivalTime: " +  TimeofArr);` ? (And remove the last Console.ReadLine();, or at least move it outside the loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your last comment I conclude you just need to get the `ReadLine` out of the loop:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome, Kindly enter your Name: ");
            EmployeeName[i] = Console.ReadLine();

            string TimeofArr = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(TimeofArr);


        }
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Good to mention that Console.ReadLine();  serve as a blocking method preventing the current thread to continue execution until a keypress has been detected. It's nice to halt console applications

Answer (score 0):

Console.ReadLine();

stops to wait for you input

Answer (score 0):

That ?

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

 namespace RegisterApp
 {
     class TimeRegister
     {
         static void Register(string[] args)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Time of Arrival Program!");
            Console.ReadLine();

            string[] EmployeeName = new string[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome, Kindly enter your Name: ");
                EmployeeName[i] = Console.ReadLine();

                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            }    
         }
     }
}
```